# Bash: not absolute script #! interpreter?

Tags: bash, interpreter

Is it possible to say to a script to search for an interpreter not in an absolute location, but in his path?

For example, writing `#!/usr/bin/php` will fail if the user has php installed somewhere else.

Just writing `#!php` does not automatically work, of course, and I couldn't find anything about it, they just all treat this method as if it was "the way"® to do it.

So, is there a standard simple syntax to say "search for it anywhere in your path"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Comment: Thaaaank you :D I love you for this